# Access loses table relationships when

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access

I need to update an MS Access app that connects to a SQL Server database. I copied the app and SQL database to my development computer, opened Access and linked the tables (100+ of them). I can see the data via Access, but all of the table relationships are lost, and the forms are giving me 3146 connection errors.

How do I straighten out the data so I can add features to the app (and eventually give the app to the client to reconnect with the original SQL Server)?

Complication: I haven't used Access in 15 years, so I'm a little rusty with it...

Comment: Could you specify some of the errors you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

The relationships are NOW handled by SQL server. They have ZERO to do with Access, or a web site, or VB6, or some .net program that simply connects to SQL server. The .net program, the VB6 program, or the software you develop using MS Access has zero to do with how the relationships are setup with the given database system (in this case SQL server).

So that web site software, or .net program, or even MS Access does not change, or control the relationships you setup on SQL server. If this were the case, then which of the programs such as .net, web site, VB6, and MS access all using the SQL server at the SAME TIME would control relationships then??

So it is not possible or practical to have the client software control or set the relationships used by SQL server, since then it would be the client software controlling this, and every program that connects to SQL server could then be different!!! (and thus no enforced relationships would be possible as all programs would have differing ideas as to how the relationships are supposed to be!!!).

Any relationships settings you have in Access are thus ignored by SQL server, since it is now SQL server that is managing the database – not Access.

Access is just a developer’s tool like VB6, or say vb.net – those programs are free to connect to SQL server. Since many different programs are able to connect to SQL server, then the programs connecting are not the ones that control relationships – it all has to be done and set on SQL server.

Access will still allow you to use the relationships diagram. You can thus still draw out relationships in that window if you want, but you note how the options to “enforce” the relationships are now gray out – they can’t be used. So it still can be a documentation tool, or a means to make a cute diagram, but as such, it will not affect the operation of SQL server.

As for you errors? Well, before you attempt to open any form, you want to click on a linked table, and see if that works first. No use to try code, forms, reports if you not FIRST sure that the table links are active and working. ONLY until such time that you can click on, and open a linked table should you be concerned with trying to use forms, code, reports etc.

I would suggest you use the linked table manager, and re-link the tables. Now, I suppose you could delete the links, but I do NOT recommend that as a first try, since the table names will likely have a dbo prefix in front of them, and this will result in all your table names being changed, and that will break near everything in your application. So really try the refresh approach, since if you have lots of tables, then you have to re-name them all if you delete the links and re-link (so try to avoid my suggesting to delete the table links and recreating them – it will save a lot of work).

So first step:
Make sure the table links works. (don’t  try code, don’t try forms, don’t try reports).

You need to ensure that a simple linked table works, and that you can simply open these linked tables. Skipping this step means everything else you attempt is folly and a waste of time.

So click on a linked table and see if you can then open + view that linked table data.

If not?

Then I would launch the linked table manager, and select all linked tables, and then force a re-fresh. (make sure you click on the box to [x] “Always prompt for new location” in the lower left corner of the linked table manager.

Comment: Thank you!!! The linked table manager is what I needed to get going. Everything is clicking along fine now!